# Can I connect two markers on google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like functionality to be, that when a user clicks on a marker at location A, a line will appear leading to location B. I'm trying to create a map which shows where people were born and where they live now.

Much like the Ryanair site, where you hover over London and you see all the destinations they fly to.

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: Please show what you have tried yourself already. It makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Hi Edgar,I haven't tried anything already :(

Comment: Very limited knowledge here

Comment: Then come back if you have tried sth. At least show us some research effort. You could take a look here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Comment: And also take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple example.
I hope I have understood your request.

This is the code:

```js
// Marker locations
var locations = [
  ['A', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['B', -33.923036, 151.139052, 5]
];
var map;
var markers = [];

function init(){
  // Create new Map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  // Get number of Locations
  var num_markers = locations.length;
  // Create Markers
  for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {  
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
      map: map,
      html: locations[i][0],
      id: i,
    });
    // Add onClick Marker Listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
      // Create Line
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [{lat:locations[0][1], lng:locations[0][2]}, {lat:locations[1][1], lng:locations[1][2]}],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      // Add line to map
      flightPath.setMap(map);
    });
    }
}

init();
```

```css
#map_canvas { 
  border:1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Or you can try on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SteeBono/x6nqL3po/194/)

Bye.